# How do I mention a users role in embed using discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am doing a userinfo embed and I want to mention the users role in embed. I tried to do it by using this line but it didn't work

```js
{
    name: 'Roles',
    value : message.member.roles
}
```

The result was like this.
[image]

Comment: What version of `discord.js` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
// ...
.addField('Roles', message.member.roles.cache.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join('\n'))
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Hey, I just realized you wanted to actually mention the roles instead of just listing them. I edited my answer with a really simple solution, sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

To mention the role (in an embed so people won't get pinged) do:

```
let member = message.mentions.users.first()
let roles = `<@&${message.guild.member(member)._roles.join('> <@&')}>`
let roleMsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Roles!`)
  .setDescription(roles)
message.channel.send(roleMsg)
```